# Current Limiter -- How to limit 16v 3.36a to 16v 1a?

Tags: power-supply, batteries

I am trying to equalize charge a 150AH Lead-Acid 12v battery. To do this, 16v at 1a needs to be delivered to the battery for a period of +-10 hours. If a 16v 3.36amps power brick (laptop charger) is directly connected to the battery then, amps drawn reaches 4.3amps and the power brick becomes extremely hot -- in danger of frying the power brick.

[image]

Comment: For all who may be interested: http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/equalizing_charge. And also http://www.trojanbattery.com/BatteryMaintenance/Charging.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Applying 16V to a lead acid 12V battery is a bit steep so try using a 2 ohm resistor in series to drop the voltage on the lead acid to about 14V. Voltage dropped is 2V and with the resistor being 2 ohm the current taken should be about 1 amp. Power dissipation of the resistor will be 2 watts but the resistor should be rated more like 10 watts for when a more discharged battery is applied.

This is probably the simplest method and you could look to using some silicon to provide better regulation.

You could even use three silicon diodes in series to drop maybe 2 to 2.5 volts. The continuous current ratings og the diode need to be round about 5 A just to be on the safe side.

Comment: Agreed, it is a bit steep -- around 10% higher than what a normal 3 stage battery charger would delivers. A 4 stage battery charger on the other hand, delivers 15-16v to a battery during maintenance/equalization mode.

Comment: I'd like to advise more but, without battery data I'm in the dark.

Comment: Thank you @Andy aka, the battery is a 12v 150ah lead acid battery. It is normally charged with a 3 stage 12v automatic battery charger. A week ago, I noticed that one cell had a specific gravity of 1.2 after charging while the other 5 cells had a specific gravity of 1.3 as expected. I feel that if an equalization charge is applied than the specific gravity might become equal for all cells.

Comment: Better battery data - like a data sheet.

Comment: The battery is Made in China -- if it has a data sheet then, most probably it is in a language that I will not understand.

Comment: I purchased a bench power supply (also made in china) for $15. It is rated at 0-16v and 2a. When connected to a battery, at 15.5v, the amps rapidly fluctuates between 0.5a and 1.5a. It will require 1 or 2 days to find out whether the power supply is able to equalize a battery.

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of supplies, constant voltage and constant current.

The supply you have is constant voltage. The supply adjusts the current output to make sure that the supply voltage output does not droop below 16V.

The other type of supply adjusts the voltage to make sure that the current stays the same.

What you want is not possible because to reduce the current you have to reduce the voltage. The best way is to use a constant current supply set to 1A and then cut the charging off when the battery reaches the fully charged voltage of about 14.75V.

Comment: Thank you, great answer. Now with the distinction between constant voltage and constant current power supplies, I see it is not possible to equalize a battery with the charger at hand.

Comment: Constant current and constant voltage are not the only choices. The bigger problem is this: when you deliver power to a battery (or other load) you cannot set both the current and the voltage. A constant voltage supply sets the voltage, and then the battery decides how much current it can accept at that voltage. A constant current supply sets the current and then in that case, the battery decides on the voltage. You can also have a supply (like a solar panel) with a complicated non-linear voltage/current characteristic. In that case, the source and load essentially "negotiate" on I and V.

Comment: To the OP, I think you want to use a constant voltage supply set at 15.5 or 16V. Don't worry about amps. Monitor the weak cell periodically to see if the SG comes up.

Comment: Worrying about the amp flow is due to heat generated by the power supply brick. I feel if it is left connected to the battery for more than 15 minutes, it will fry the power brick.

Comment: I wonder if buying a lab power supply would solve the situation.

Comment: Would you consider buying an off-the-shelf charger? Just make sure it is capable of "equalization." I have a battery back up in my barn for some electronics. The charger stays on all the time. Every once in a while it runs an equalization cycle all by itself. I think it is an 80 Ah battery and a 10 A charger. The charger has been running continuously for around 2 years. The battery has been there longer than that. I check the water level, but I haven't checked the battery capacity or measured SG.

Comment: I can't seem to find a battery charger with "equalization" capability. I have a bench/lab power supply now that I purchased for $15, it is rated at 0v-15v and 0a-2a -- it seems to be doing the job.

Answer (score 1):

The traditional current limiter for crude chargers was a suitably rated filament light bulb.  When it is glowing orange to yellow hot it works as a current controlled resistor that will reduce the voltage that reaches the battery if the current is too high.  It is a very good robust low tech solution for float charging (if you top up cell with water occasionally as required).

You can switch in a beefier lamp for a period (of time or until the voltage reaches some set point) if you want it to start with fast charging if your charger can cope.

You do want to regulate somewhat as a 16V supply will eventually dry out a 12V lead acid battery cells by boiling (electrolysis) of the water when full charge at about 14.2V has been reached.